Exodus | Death of the Firstborn | Why weren't the Hebrews' animals slain?
So I've been reading through Exodus a lot lately, and one of the things that stood out to me was the death of the firstborn of the animals during the final plague / strike. Now, the firstborn of the Hebrew people were redeemed by the blood of the year-old sheep & goats that was placed upon the door frame of their houses. However, there is no instruction to either take their animals into their homes or else to place blood along the enclosures for their animals (stables / barns / etc). So then, by what sign did the Destroyer know not to destroy them? What is the spiritual significance of this, if any? Let me know your thoughts :)

A lot of animals in those days stayed in the home, instead of in a separate building.

@DJClayworth During the plague of Hail the people are warned to bring their animals in from the field lest they die. So I don't think they normally kept all of their livestock in their homes.

In the field during the day and in the house at night.

@DJClayworth do you have any source to backup the idea that the animals were kept in the home at night?

Lots. Let's start with this one. https://biblearchaeology.org/research/chronological-categories/life-and-ministry-of-jesus-and-apostles/4866-away-in-a-manger-but-not-in-a-barn-an-archaeological-look-at-the-nativity and this one https://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/ancient-cultures/ancient-israel/daily-life-in-ancient-israel/

@DJClayworth The link is describing an inn (not a general house), and even when talking about the general house structure it says that sometimes there would be a manger. Also, this is describing houses much further in the future than the exodus. However, I do see your meaning that at least some houses may have had attached mangers.

No it's not. Read the caption to the house diagram ("A traditional Israelite “four-room” house which became a standard house plan") and the section below it called "Inns and Innkeepers" which explain why Luke is talking about a house, not an inn.

@DJClayworth again, the article itself says that a house may or may not have had a manger, and this is a house plan from a different time period and region.

I didn't say every animal would be in the house, but I wanted to point out a lot did. If you don't think it's helpful information that's fine.

@DJClayworth I do appreciate your input :) But yes, I am concerned with all the animals, not just some of them. For none of them were lost to the Hebrews - only the Egyptians.

The context of the first-born death relates to the Egyptians and showing a difference between them and Israel.

And all the firstborn in the land of Egypt shall die, from the firstborn of Pharaoh that sitteth upon his throne, even unto the firstborn of the maidservant that is behind the mill; and all the firstborn of beasts.  And there shall be a great cry throughout all the land of Egypt, such as there was none like it, nor shall be like it any more.  But against any of the children of Israel shall not a dog move his tongue, against man or beast: that ye may know how that the LORD doth put a difference between the Egyptians and Israel. Exo 11:5-7

This is similar to the plague of darkness that happened across all the land, yet there was light for the Israelites.

And the LORD said unto Moses, Stretch out thine hand toward heaven, that there may be darkness over the land of Egypt, even darkness which may be felt. And Moses stretched forth his hand toward heaven; and there was a thick darkness in all the land of Egypt three days: They saw not one another, neither rose any from his place for three days: but all the children of Israel had light in their dwellings. Exo 10:21-23

So, to answer the OP, the Destroyer knew the difference between those acting in faith, following Moses' instructions, and those who did not believe.

I don't disagree with what you've said. However, the way it is phrased suggests that the Destroyer only passes over when it sees the blood- and as best I can tell there was no blood protecting the Israelite's animals. Not a big deal - but often times in the OT there is a deeper meaning to be had when we consider what is said concerning the animals. For instance, this could be a teaching about how one is not above their Master - how a servant shares in the fate of the one they serve.
